# fadeOut() single div over multiple

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have three divs with a class "page". For each div there is a "info" div that shows some informations about the div.

What I wanted to achieve is that when I click some text under the "page" div it will fadeOut and the "info" will fadeIn.

Even if I know almost nothing of jQuery, I managed to get this working. My HTML is:

```
    <div id="content">

       <div class="page"><p class="click">Click me to open</p></div>
       <div class="info"><div class="closebut"></div></div>

       <div class="page"><p class="click">Click me to open</p></div>
       <div class="info"><div class="closebut"></div></div>

       <div class="page"><p class="click">Click me to open</p></div>
       <div class="info"><div class="closebut"></div></div>

    </div>
```

and my jQuery is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".info").hide();

    $("p.click").click(function(){ 
        $(".page").fadeOut("slow", function(){ $(".info").fadeIn(); });
    });

    $(".closebut").click(function(){
        $(".info").fadeOut("slow", function(){ $(".page").fadeIn(); });
    });
});
```

So, when the document loads, jQuery hides the ".info" divs. When I click on the paragraph ".click" the ".page" will fadeOut and, at the end, ".info" will fadeIn. Then I have a little image of a X working as closing button (.closebut).

Everything works just fine. However when I click the first "p.click" EVERY ".page" will fadeOut and EVERY ".info" will fadeIn.

Since I'll need 5 and more ".page" + ".info", what is the easiest way to fadeOut/fadeIn a single div per time?

I mean, without creating more classes in the html and extending the jQuery code.. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How is the result being generated? Is the page hard coded, or fetched from database?

Comment: Hard coded! It will contain a little image gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `next()` and `prev()` functions, along with `parent()`.

```
$("p.click").click(function(){ 
    var p = $(this);
    p.parent().prev().prev(".page").fadeOut("slow", function(){ p.parent().prev(".info").fadeIn(); });
});

$(".closebut").click(function(){
    var but = $(this);
    but.parent(".info").fadeOut("slow", function(){ but.parent().prev(".page").fadeIn(); });
});
```

This works because, inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Put each "group of div" in another divs.

```
<div class="parent">
       <div class="page"></div>
       <div class="info"><div class="closebut"></div></div>
       <div id="text"><p class="click">Click me to open</p></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("p.click").click(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find(".page").fadeOut("slow", function(){ $(this).parent().find(".info").fadeIn(); });
});
```

That's my idea.

Comment: I'm really really sorry, I put the wrong code for the HTML elements. The <p class="click"></p> should go INSIDE the <div class="page"></div>. I fixed that in the first post..

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `parent` and the `prev` element for the clicked item so the clicked item is `this`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZZyY/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".info").hide();

    $("p.click").click(function(){ 
        var ele = $(this); 
        $(this).fadeOut("slow", function(){
           $(this).parent().prev('.info').fadeIn(); });
    });

    $(".closebut").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).parent().prev('.page').fadeIn(); 

        });
    });
});
```

I hope this can help :)